# What does this RDD look like?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Is there any spark streaming documentation that explains what is the content of the RDDs that a in the stream obtained using:

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

I have tried printing this stream and it looks like

```
(None,<line>)
(None,<line>)
(None,<line>)
```

Hence `lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])` is used to do a map transformation on the stream of RDDs which will then look something like:

```
(<line>)
(<line>)
(<line>)
```

My question is , if the createStream function returns a stream of RDDs that look like (None,) what is is this tuple supposed to contain ? and why is it none?

(I am looking at this example [Spark streaming kafka wordcount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py) )

Answer (score 1):

Data read from Kafka stream are exactly the same you have written there before.

To explain the `None`, each message in kafka is a **key-value pair**. That means in your case messages don't have keys but only values (= lines of text for wordcount).

That also explains usage of `kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])` which extracts just the value (line) from the message and ignores the empty key.